# How to read Schema from the config table and attach to Pyspark DataFrame?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have 50 tables in my on premise server. I want to migrate those 50 tables from on-premise to delta table in data bricks. But every table has specific schema defined but i need to design the single adf pipeline to move those fifty tables from on-premises to delta table.

How to attach the schema to the data frame at the run time based on the table name ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use mapping data flows for this scenario:

1. Create a static table/file with the list of your tables.
2. Add a for each loop in ADF pipeline.
3. Within foreach, create a mapping data flow.
4. As a source provide your on-prem database (schema will be detected automatically).
5. Delta table as a destination (sink).

Mapping data flows are spark-based, therefore you can see in "projection" tab that it is translated to the spark type already.